# Add fragment from ViewModel in MVVM architecture

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am using `DataBinding` and following **MVVM architecture**, now i am stuck on how to add new fragment from `ViewModel` as we need defined click event on `ViewModel`. Here is my `MainViewModel` class

```
public class MainViewModel {
    private Context context;

    public MainViewModel (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

here is my xml where i have defined click event

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{viewmodel::onClick}"
            android:text="click me"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

now how can i get `supportFragmentManager` or `childFragmentManager` from my ViewModel class? I have tried to use `activity.getSupportFragmentManager()` and `activity.getChildFragmentManager()` but it doesn't have that kind of method.

I know we can add fragment with following code

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).
            add(R.id.container, fragment, "").addToBackStack("main").commit();
```

but how to do it in `ViewModel` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have your `Context` available, you have two possibilities:

```
public class MainViewModel {
    private Context context;

    public MainViewModel (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //use context:
        ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

        //OR use the views context:
        if(v.getContext() instanceof AppCompatActivity) {
            ((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
        }            
    }    
}
```

It may be useful to check whether the context is an instance of your activity (like `MainActivity`) or `AppCompatActivity`, or if it is `null` before calling any method.

Comment: It is bad practice to keep context from View in ViewModel

Comment: @kazimad you are right, That's why MVVM was created in the first place, not to hold reference of android (view) related stuff in the ViewModel.

Comment: @MeHdi i have a similar problem, what would you suggest then?

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh Would you please explain more? You want some fragment to be added to backstack?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible but here is what i suggest:

Define an interface and let the Activity or Fragment implement this interface

```
public interface FragmentProvider {
    void showFragment(...);
}
```

Pass an instance of FragmentProvider into your ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel {
    private Context context;
    private FragmentProvider provider;

    public MainViewModel (FragmentProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
        // delegate the action
        provider.showFragment(...);
   }
```

}

Comment: yes that's available way, but i am not sure whether that will be good idea or not when working with mvvm.

Comment: I would like to go with EventBus kind of idea this is better solution then the first accepted answer here.

Comment: I would like to go with EventBus kind of idea this is better solution then the first accepted answer here.